# Calculation vibration with accelerometer (LSM303D sensor)with STM32

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, stm32

I want to write an algorithm for ageing or condition monitoring of fluid valves.I read something about condition monitoring of valves and finally, I decided to calculate the vibration of the valve with accelerometer sensor.
Currently, I am working with LSM303D and ADXL345 sensors.
I am getting raw data from this sensor(LSM303D) like

```
X-axis = -2587 negative
Y -axis = -2230 negative
Z - axis = 16063
```

Is this mean acceleration is in Z axis direction?
I have fixed my sensor on the valve(There is no physical movement) and want to measure the vibration while switching on and off the valve.

How to proceed with my raw data for creating an algorithm for vibration calculation with STM32 controller?
Please explain about the raw data from sensor.

Sensor Datasheet
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1c/9e/71/05/4e/b7/4d/d1/DM00057547.pdf/files/DM00057547.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00057547.pdf

STM32 Datasheet:
http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/95/3c/2e/5b/21/09/45/a6/DM00115237.pdf/files/DM00115237.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00115237.pdf

OutPUT:
X axis
-2320,-2288,-2290,-2273,-2308,-2264,-2258,-2302,-2361,-2361,-2263,-2349,-2338,-2301,-2383,-2311,-2313,-2313,-2354,-2351,-2358,-2254,-2411,-2336,-2336,-2269,-2232,-2354,-2300,-2356,-2326,-2368,-2368,-2295,-2370,-2345,-2344,-2342,-2323,-2323,-2341,-2290,-2292,-2328,-2363,-2347,-2347,-2303,-2330,-2384,-2306,-2318,-2348,-2348,-2289,-2300,-2384,-2301,-2269,-2269,-2391,-2314,-2294,-2327,-2343,-2331,-2331,-2247,-2313,-2403,-2284,-2336,-2336,-2323,-2340,-2276,-2277,-2353,-2400,-2400,-2321,-2296,-2317,-2314,-2356,-2359,-2359,-2313,-2250,-2312,-2334,-2314,-2314,-2298,-2317,-2279,-2368,-2331,-2560,-2304,-2298,-2327,-2301,-2332,-2330,-2330,-2269,-2300,-2300,-2332,-2271,-2057,-2313,-2316,-2309,-2257,-2362,-2406,-2406,-2290,-2298,-2373,-2314,-2260,-2277,-2277,-2323,-2332,-2189,-2314,-2339,-2553,-2297,-2332,-2327,-2289,-2347,-2326,-2326,-2319,-2361,-2330,-2352,-2329,-2550,-2294,-2311,-2312,-2327,-2344,-2362,-2360,-2280,-2307,-2307,-2370,-2307,-2211,-2264,-2313,-2354,-2317,-2344,-2352,-2288,-2288,-2266,-2307,-2297,-2356,-2334,-2302,-2307,-2307,-2326,-2289,-2345,-2387,-2378,-2308,-2308,-2323,-2323,-2273,-2348,-2288,-2288,-2314,-2255,-2299,-2335,-2306,-2327,-2327,-2267,-2313,-2319,-2275,-2307,-2354,-2354,-2299,-2288,-2279,-2337,-2325,-2325,-2256,-2312,-2294,-2295,-2294,-2368,-2368,-2326,-2324,-2320,-2303,-2310,-2325,-2325,-2310,-2291,-2309,-2328,-2364,-2364,-2284,-2354,-2376,-2311,-2335,-2342,-2342,-2336,-2322,-2317,-2276,-2385,-2362,-2268,-2107,-2363,-2307,-2292,-2296,-2356,-2288,-2288,-2355,-2372,-2303,-2348,-2279,-2346,-2346,-2238,-2320,-2323,-2280,-2318,-2345,-2345,-2318,-2323,-2316,-2316,-2307,-2324,-2324,-2376,-2251,-2347,-2375,-2300,-2300,-2399,-2318,-2283,-2375,-2356,-2316,-2316,-2260,-2418,-2341,-2347,-2327,-2327,-2308,-2358,-2335,-2344,-2350,-2264,-2264,-2377,-2328,-2323,-2347,-2351,-2352,-2352,-2290,-2369,-2307,-2333,-2306,-2540,-2284,-2343,-2353,-2283,-2301,-2310,-2548,-2292,-2358,-2321,-2275,-2290,-2267,-2267,-2378,-2330,-2319,-2356,-2315,-2337,-2337,-2360,-2385,-2358,-2320,-2304,-2290,-2290,-2329,-2362,-2318,-2335,-2303,-2303,-2358,-2305,-2293,-2288,-2244,-2255,-2255,-2339,-2337,-2375,-2296,-2243,-2053,-2309,-2346,-2410,-2333,-2287,-2316,-2316,-2362,-2331,-2291,-2350,-2394,-2323,-2323,-2377,-2313,-2324,-2327,-2322,-2322,-2258,-2325,-2356,-2337,-2376,-2351,-2351,-2286,-2255,-2347,-2376,-2359,-2343,-2343,-2389,-2303,-2302,-2384,-2298,-2298,-2313,-2344,-2323,-2273,-2295,-2316,-2316,-2369,-2343,-2287,-2280,-2348,-2544,-2288,-2279,-2380,-2349,-2241,-2344,-2344,-2366,-2363,-2350,-2303,-2335,-2340,-2340,-2309,-2348,-2304,-2354,-2644,-2461,-2404,-2404,-2170,-2374,-2299,-2268,-2334,-2334,-2364,-2288,-2337,-2329,-2401,-2241,-2241,-2247,-2339,-2395,-2312,-2369,-2526,-2270,-2298,-2318,-2285,-2254,-2316,-2349,-2349,-2334,-2274,-2297,-2352,-2321,-2321,-2293,-2358,-2289,-2341,-2329,-2336,-2336,-2360,-2311,-2345,-2344,-2321,-2321,-2333,-2285,-2284,-2325,-2360,-2280,-2280,-2303,-2343,-2237,-2317,-2373,-2535,-2279,-2309,-2287,-2308,-2289,-2334,-2334,-2293,-2330,-2315,-2271,-2300,-2346,-2346,-2336,-2287,-2308,-2320,-2315,-2347,-2347,-2302,-2283,-2267,-2312,-2288,-2096,-2352,-2298,-2252,-2290,-2341,-2328,-2290,-2290,-2265,-2242,-2326,-2262,-2300,-2074,-2330,-2322,-2382,-2304,-2316,-2337,-2337,-2209,-2358,-2339,-2285,-2319,-2280,-2280,-2327,-2299,-2329,-2331,-2317,-2347,-2347,-2343,-2334,-2255,-2295,-2295,-2295,-2315,-2343,-2365,-2366,-2326,-2542,-2286,-2331,-2343,-2370,-2317,-2291,-2270,-2270,-2343,-2261,-2335,-2343,-2297,-2297,-2359,-2290,-2293,-2350,-2314,-2315,-2315,-2388,-2357,-2335,-2382,-2235,-2052,-2308,-2379,-2340,-2313,-2260,-2301,-2301,-2225,-2323,-2286,-2383,-2370,-2504,-2248,-2274,-2317,-2282,-2285,-2226,-2145,-2401,-2341,-2361,-2422,-2336,-2288,-2288,-2386,-2357,-2294,-2310,-2295,-2117,-2373,-2260,-2274,-2289,-2379,-2313,-2313,-2256,-2300,-2344,-2293,-2296,-2312,-2312,-2363,-2328,-2347,-2351,-2294,-2092,-2348,-2381,-2347,-2229,-2275,-2328,-2328,-2379,-2256,-2362,-2331,-2347,-2360,-2360,-2279,-2269,-2332,-2374

Y Axis

-2485,-2478,-2511,-2486,-2486,-2475,-2490,-2517,-2482,-2505,-2457,-2457,-2468,-2471,-2475,-2498,-2513,-2489,-2531,-2531,-2509,-2435,-2473,-2493,-2486,-2428,-2428,-2485,-2473,-2513,-2459,-2514,-2510,-2456,-2456,-2519,-2511,-2569,-2466,-2484,-2524,-2524,-2475,-2468,-2518,-2469,-2443,-2513,-2513,-2494,-2460,-2503,-2466,-2497,-2497,-2460,-2472,-2528,-2473,-2479,-2480,-2480,-2448,-2425,-2447,-2523,-2552,-2447,-2447,-2513,-2532,-2480,-2459,-2511,-2511,-2493,-2472,-2447,-2477,-2542,-2434,-2434,-2472,-2484,-2477,-2503,-2472,-2472,-2478,-2519,-2501,-2449,-2453,-2477,-2477,-2491,-2471,-2480,-2507,-2473,-2449,-2449,-2514,-2457,-2473,-2513,-2501,-2501,-2437,-2520,-2479,-2481,-2468,-2497,-2497,-2523,-2488,-2454,-2525,-2470,-2470,-2448,-2487,-2484,-2477,-2460,-2476,-2476,-2515,-2467,-2443,-2449,-2480,-2480,-2451,-2459,-2470,-2477,-2489,-2463,-2463,-2492,-2500,-2469,-2491,-2475,-2528,-2528,-2438,-2442,-2506,-2499,-2489,-2461,-2486,-2485,-2483,-2492,-2523,-2453,-2453,-2484,-2458,-2509,-2484,-2497,-2433,-2433,-2515,-2479,-2507,-2519,-2485,-2483,-2500,-2500,-2477,-2510,-2506,-2488,-2480,-2497,-2497,-2488,-2464,-2452,-2496,-2487,-2487,-2512,-2464,-2489,-2484,-2496,-2477,-2477,-2467,-2478,-2500,-2452,-2534,-2490,-2490,-2499,-2485,-2463,-2457,-2501,-2501,-2471,-2448,-2524,-2480,-2473,-2503,-2503,-2481,-2525,-2497,-2449,-2511,-2483,-2483,-2513,-2459,-2501,-2462,-2489,-2489,-2496,-2494,-2468,-2453,-2464,-2537,-2537,-2484,-2520,-2442,-2514,-2505,-2463,-2517,-2523,-2523,-2471,-2454,-2444,-2442,-2519,-2519,-2521,-2480,-2457,-2455,-2492,-2471,-2471,-2454,-2493,-2510,-2480,-2458,-2489,-2489,-2485,-2492,-2487,-2459,-2466,-2466,-2519,-2446,-2500,-2527,-2459,-2489,-2489,-2479,-2469,-2484,-2482,-2477,-2480,-2480,-2479,-2494,-2514,-2485,-2474,-2474,-2493,-2505,-2495,-2471,-2496,-2501,-2501,-2438,-2495,-2469,-2488,-2481,-2521,-2521,-2508,-2490,-2465,-2480,-2455,-2524,-2524,-2499,-2502,-2481,-2472,-2490,-2490,-2432,-2494,-2543,-2478,-2462,-2487,-2487,-2525,-2491,-2500,-2491,-2449,-2490,-2490,-2459,-2506,-2476,-2487,-2493,-2480,-2480,-2498,-2472,-2506,-2473,-2457,-2457,-2503,-2515,-2479,-2486,-2482,-2521,-2521,-2491,-2509,-2505,-2496,-2483,-2483,-2453,-2495,-2519,-2440,-2548,-2482,-2482,-2427,-2532,-2495,-2466,-2436,-2443,-2443,-2500,-2444,-2458,-2455,-2489,-2489,-2510,-2497,-2494,-2510,-2519,-2485,-2485,-2458,-2509,-2466,-2519,-2483,-2523,-2523,-2482,-2511,-2492,-2463,-2470,-2470,-2494,-2481,-2487,-2495,-2493,-2513,-2513,-2490,-2495,-2505,-2476,-2470,-2470,-2480,-2502,-2479,-2420,-2470,-2479,-2479,-2491,-2530,-2512,-2503,-2538,-2446,-2446,-2447,-2562,1029,-2413,-2366,-2607,-2607,-2426,-2440,-2552,-2446,-2503,-2517,-2517,-2428,-2496,-2462,-2489,-2525,-2513,-2513,-2456,-2476,-2500,-2535,-2524,-2453,-2453,-2534,-2493,-2480,-2487,-2437,-2437,-2470,-2514,-2465,-2532,-2511,-2448,-2448,-2479,-2532,-2519,-2507,-2463,-2510,-2510,-2459,-2461,-2483,-2488,-2520,-2520,-2485,-2455,-2491,-2492,-2445,-2458,-2458,-2477,-2489,-2492,-2478,-2506,-2501,-2501,-2489,-2485,-2481,-2480,-2486,-2486,-2471,-2453,-2505,-2473,-2478,-2472,-2472,-2493,-2487,-2491,-2479,-2492,-2518,-2518,-2520,-2508,-2503,-2465,-2501,-2488,-2488,-2485,-4231,-2508,-2483,-2376,-2474,-2474,-2453,-2503,-2498,-2455,-2495,-2495,-2495,-2517,-2455,-2470,-2441,-2478,-2478,-2470,-2500,-2484,-2473,-2418,-2477,-2477,-2512,-2459,-2503,-2473,-2464,-2476,-2476,-2480,-2497,-2499,-2501,-2492,-2492,-2443,-2478,-2500,-2476,-2486,-2529,-2529,-2455,-2521,-2463,-2482,-2460,-2460,-2510,-2506,-2470,-2484,-2473,-2441,-2441,-2500,-2489,-2502,-2496,-2415,-2504,-2504,-2518,-2417,-2500,-2498,-2460,-2501,-2501,-2498,-2460,-2449,-2465,-2499,-2499,-2496,-2479,-2521,-2513,-2513,-2479,-2479,-2480,-2546,-2514,-2502,-2479,-2479,-2446,-2484,-2531,-2524,-2533,-2489,-2489,-2486,-2444,-2477,-2462,-2474,-2513,-2513,-2485,-2475,-2463,-2438,-2477,-2477,-2470,-2481,-2467,-2497,-2454,-2475,-2475,-2507,-2477,-2499,-2464,-2501,-2501,-2523,-2502,-2452,-2497,-2488,-2456,-2456,-2487,-2504,-2490,-2472,-2547,-2458,-2458,-2469,-2429

Z Axis:

16068,16050,16097,16178,16142,16294,16038,16070,16184,16207,16125,16174,16246,16246,16161,16117,16132,16128,16104,16281,16326,16070,16012,16147,16174,15961,16097,16121,15919,16175,16173,16092,16019,16144,16074,16136,16136,16031,16016,16123,16077,16166,16019,16019,16169,16132,16150,16075,16100,15896,16152,16047,16215,16183,16040,16178,16178,16127,16099,16035,16169,16243,16323,16067,16150,16071,16144,16052,16118,15931,16187,16242,16096,16243,16090,16170,16170,16108,16137,16060,16081,16184,16323,16067,16078,16148,16104,16011,16174,16174,16123,16133,16196,16109,16117,16088,16088,16159,16153,16112,16127,16215,16215,16064,16046,16073,16081,16141,16351,16095,16143,16171,16145,16081,16226,16339,16083,16078,16209,15997,16071,16181,16181,16128,16070,16077,16018,16163,16293,16037,16146,16207,16147,16041,16124,16124,16093,16129,15987,16152,16175,16311,16055,16114,16116,16245,16052,16125,16148,16111,16111,16157,16040,15968,16174,16213,16106,16052,16161,16048,16142,16142,16147,16030,16102,16079,16153,16178,16129,16179,16179,16079,16060,16020,16103,16074,16078,16078,16164,16182,16163,16105,16046,16046,16160,16068,16060,16074,16125,16131,16131,16160,16026,16019,16153,16048,15924,16180,16087,16150,16048,16072,16040,16040,16139,16106,16077,16262,16117,16212,16212,16239,16043,16219,16119,16012,16105,16105,16111,16044,16161,16073,16020,16020,16135,16160,16096,16076,16110,16053,16053,16151,16066,16068,16129,16123,16114,15886,16142,16199,16181,16064,16090,16043,16099,16099,16128,16058,16016,16043,16167,16177,16177,16010,16158,16086,16112,16115,15888,16144,16135,16226,16110,16121,16053,15916,16172,16075,16061,16119,16137,16159,16159,16181,16075,16039,16242,16121,15977,15977,16141,16155,16207,16069,16107,16107,16114,16083,16102,16008,16071,16119,16119,16028,16124,16225,16022,16134,16130,16130,16137,16174,16086,16159,16056,16088,16088,16186,16154,16050,16092,16159,16146,16146,16070,16176,16225,16088,16118,16118,16093,16289,16118,16091,16141,16207,16207,16173,16151,16048,16195,16141,16202,16202,16058,16040,16145,16190,16140,16140,16159,16163,16153,16151,16106,16178,16178,16044,16064,16223,16131,16101,15955,16211,16151,16161,15998,16099,16053,16053,16085,16005,16134,16144,16088,15872,16128,16072,16029,16230,16109,16039,16081,16081,16267,16176,16049,16156,16162,16162,16130,16138,16018,16119,16180,16129,16129,16178,16091,16108,16169,16191,16191,16064,16070,16117,16160,16110,16082,16082,16096,15991,16130,16194,16068,15930,15930,16132,16121,16067,16105,16087,16087,16183,16269,16118,15998,16180,16129,16129,16128,16156,16166,16065,16136,16248,16248,11913,15882,16067,16164,16004,16159,16159,16201,16050,16129,16144,16119,16129,16129,16028,16126,16152,16117,16107,15903,16159,16138,16140,16131,16075,16110,15895,16151,16064,16168,16116,16131,16160,16160,16150,16130,16059,16141,16128,16195,16195,16216,16053,16097,16167,16122,16122,16077,16173,16031,16131,16092,16099,16099,16163,16126,16065,16137,16165,16342,16086,16050,16156,16087,16107,16169,16169,16178,16061,16091,16061,16260,16133,16133,16117,16174,16108,16164,16162,16311,16055,16219,16143,16127,16105,16121,15902,16158,16194,16044,16178,16057,16085,15329,15329,16090,16066,16131,16113,16163,16352,16096,16080,16057,16111,16146,16134,16134,16162,16092,16139,16120,16144,16028,16028,16142,16171,16066,16041,16154,16366,16110,16110,16128,16117,16125,16091,16091,16149,16050,16024,16154,16186,16072,16072,16090,16143,16206,16141,16073,16052,16052,16123,16158,16159,16197,16135,16135,16119,16128,16090,16063,16139,16153,16153,16019,16072,16128,16153,16129,16180,16180,16157,16207,16126,16158,16066,16066,16102,16177,16104,16202,16104,16159,16159,16090,16071,16070,16115,16127,15924,16180,16088,16122,16075,16085,16105,16105,16187,16056,16010,16150,16151,16166,16166,16124,16088,16166,16123,15991,15944,16200,16124,16152,16093,16106,16057,16057,16177,16163,16167,16021,16095,16106,16106,16088,16170,16162,16144,16266,16266,16115,16135,16159,16021,16240,16162,16162,16004,16154,16182,16073,16129,16299

Comment: Add a datasheet or more like read it. Infromation about the output data should included in that.

Comment: Hi, Here I am sending datasheet http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1c/9e/71/05/4e/b7/4d/d1/DM00057547.pdf/files/DM00057547.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00057547.pdf

Comment: In order to develop an algorithm, you need to understand what it is that you want to accomplish. I'm assuming that you want to determine an impending failure of the valve by detecting a change in some characteristic of its vibrations. Vibration is a very complex topic; what aspect do you care about (i.e., Magnitude, peak frequency, frequency spectrum, steady state or transient)? When do you care? (at valve position, during valve movement, at certain flow rates)? Are there other sources of vibration you need to account for (multiple valves, on moving vehicle, other moving parts, people)?

Answer (score 0):

The reference is relative to the chip position. See the datasheet for this.

Don't forget that gravity is an acceleration, so when the accelerometer is still, the output vector points downwards (in the Earth reference). You can store an initial value (an average on several points in the best case), and substract this value from your datapoints.

The best way to debug this is to plot the values in real time.